# How to make a static version of a Map holding getters/setters of an object?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have a map I build when called on object that provides caller with variable names as key and getter/setter pair as values.  This works as expected.  My issue is that I build it every time I call for it, and I am wondering if there is a way to declare it static and supply only the object I want to invoke it on, that way I'm not building the map every time since getters and setters don't change at runtime.

What I have:

```
package main;
import org.javatuples.Pair;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public interface MapPackHelperI 
{
     public Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> getNameToGetterSetterMap();    
}
```

```
package main;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.javatuples.Pair;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class SomeStruct implements MapPackHelperI
{
    private long somelong;
    private String somestring;
    private List<Float> somelistfloat;
    private SomeEnum someenum;

    public  Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> getNameToGetterSetterMap()
    {
        Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> nameToGetterSetterMap = new HashMap<>();        
        nameToGetterSetterMap.put("somelong", Pair.with( this::getSomelong, (Consumer<Long>)this::setSomelong));
        nameToGetterSetterMap.put("somestring", Pair.with( this::getSomestring, (Consumer<String>)this::setSomestring));
        nameToGetterSetterMap.put("somelistfloat", Pair.with( this::getSomelistfloat, (Consumer<List<Float>>)this::setSomelistfloat));
        nameToGetterSetterMap.put("someenum", Pair.with( this::getSomeenum, (Consumer<SomeEnum>)this::setSomeenum));
        return nameToGetterSetterMap;
    }

    public long getSomelong() {
        return this.somelong;
    }

    public void setSomelong(long somelong) {
        this.somelong = somelong;
    }

    public String getSomestring() {
        return this.somestring;
    }

    public void setSomestring(String somestring) {
        this.somestring = somestring;
    }

    public List<Float> getSomelistfloat() {
        return this.somelistfloat;
    }

    public void setSomelistfloat(List<Float> somelistfloat) {
        this.somelistfloat = somelistfloat;
    }

    public SomeEnum getSomeenum() {
        return this.someenum;
    }

    public void setSomeenum(SomeEnum someenum) {
        this.someenum = someenum;
    }

   // ... hashcode, toString, and equals, not relevant for the example
}
```

This allows me to do from elsewhere:

```
public static String serialize(MapPackHelperI objectToSerialize) 
{
   Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> nameToGetterSetterMap = objectToSerialize.getNameToGetterSetterMap();
   for(Entry<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> current : nameToGetterSetterMap.entrySet())
   {
       String name = current.getKey();
       Supplier getter = current.getValue().getValue0();
       //code that serializes into string with name and getter regardless of the MapPackHelperI I pass in
   }

  // return the string representation of the object. I have another method that uses the same map to go the other way with the setter.
}
```

Like I said, this works, but I'm instantiating and filling the map each time I call on it.

Is there a way to have `SomeStruct` have a `public static  Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> nameToGetterSetterMap = new HashMap<>();` (or some equivalent) such that  `public  Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> getNameToGetterSetterMap()` takes as parameter an instantiated `SomeStruct` and just applies the calls to that particular object.

I tried doing a static map and filling it with `SomeStruct::getSomelong` and so on, but the compiler said I can't do that.

Comment: Why are you creating the map every time you call `getNameToGetterSetterMap`? You could create it once in your constructor and add it as an instance variable.

Comment: You tried doing a static map and get an error. Please show code and the error.

Comment: there is no error, just trying to be more efficient and create less objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Member field

The answer seems so obvious that I must be missing something: Cache the newly constructed map as a private member field.

```java
public class SomeStruct implements MapPackHelperI
{
    …
    private Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> map = 
        Map.of( 
            "somelong", Pair.with( this::getSomelong, (Consumer<Long>)this::setSomelong) ,
            "somestring", Pair.with( this::getSomestring, (Consumer<String>)this::setSomestring) ,
            "somelistfloat", Pair.with( this::getSomelistfloat, (Consumer<List<Float>>)this::setSomelistfloat) ,
            "someenum", Pair.with( this::getSomeenum, (Consumer<SomeEnum>)this::setSomeenum)
        ) ;

    public  Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> getNameToGetterSetterMap()
    {
        return this.map ;
    }

…
```

Be aware that the `Map` implementation returned by [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) is shallowly [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable).

You should be able to make that `map` member variable `static`. But unless you know for certain you are doing a zillion instantiations of `SomeStruct`, I would consider that a micro-optimization that is not worth the bother.

```
private static Map<String, Pair<Supplier, Consumer>> map = …
```

---

By the way, that [*JavaTuples*](https://www.javatuples.org) library looks nifty. But with [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java 16+, you might consider writing your own little `Pair` class.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly it. For some reason I just didn't think of this, but it's perfect.

Comment: Will probably make it static since it's for a bunch of data classes that will be flying back and forth and some of them there might be quite a bit of.  I've been using JavaTuples since 2014 (or therabouts), well before Java 16 :D